# Why impurites (more specifically sugar) lower the specific heat capacity of water

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

We,for a school project, found the specific heat capacity of 6 sugar solutions dissolved in the same 100ml of water (all standard laboratory procedures followed ie Apparatus washed to remove impurites etc). After a graph of specific heat capcity vs mass of sugar solution was plotted, it was found that specific heat capacity decreases as sugar content increases.

Can anyone provide guidance on exactly why impurites decreases the sepcific heat capcaity of water please?

Answer (score 1):

Water has an unusually high specific heat capacity.  Most materials which are not water have lower specific heat capacity than water. This includes (dry) sugar.  So if you had a container of water and a container of (dry) sugar next to each other, you system would have less total heat capacity that those same two containers filled with an equivalent mass of pure water.

There is a slight increase in heat capacity when you go from (dry sugar plus pure water) to (sugar water), because the sugar molecules in solution have degrees of freedom which the sugar molecules in the crystal do not.  But the mixture does not get you all the way back up to the heat capacity of pure water.